# Jquery grep or map object array with multiple search criterias

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, filter, grep

I have a price list in JSON:

```
  {Products: [{AdminID: 137, ProduktID: "07.1434", itemName: "Repaplast", itemColor: "0000, 5030", MalKode: "1-3", …}{AdminID: 6, ProduktID: "07.1436", itemName: "Repaplast grå", itemColor: "0070", MalKode: "1-3", …}{AdminID: 146, ProduktID: "90.0905", itemName: "Mixer Gun", itemColor: null, MalKode: "", …}{AdminID: 89, ProduktID: "02.0135", itemName: "Repaplast Primer NEW FORMULA", itemColor: "", MalKode: "5-3", …}]}
```

The list is about 400 products long.

Say I want to limit the list showing only specific products based on the field `ProduktID` (which is unique). Let's say I have a list of products in an offer:

07.1438, 01, 1340, 05, 04531, 02.0135

Where comma is the separator.

How can I `.grep` or `.map` the objects array based on these inputs?
Do I have to search one by one and then combine the results into another object? Or is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` and `array#find`. It will result in filtering the `products` based on the `product ids` string.

```js
const productIds = '07.1438, 01,1340, 05,04531, 02.0135';

const products = [{AdminID: 137, ProduktID: "07.1438", itemName: "Repaplast", itemColor: "0000, 5030", MalKode: "1-3",},{AdminID: 6, ProduktID: "07.1436", itemName: "Repaplast grå", itemColor: "0070", MalKode: "1-3",},{AdminID: 146, ProduktID: "90.0905", itemName: "Mixer Gun", itemColor: null, MalKode: "",},{AdminID: 89, ProduktID: "02.0135", itemName: "Repaplast Primer NEW FORMULA", itemColor: "", MalKode: "5-3",}];

var result = products.filter( o => productIds.split(',').find(productId => o.ProduktID === productId.trim()));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I still get error on the "filter" keyword. Error sais: "products.filter is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const wanted   = ['07.1438', '01','1340', '05', '04531', '02.0135'];
const products = [
  {
    AdminID  : 137, 
    ProduktID: "07.1434", 
    itemName : "Repaplast", 
    itemColor: "0000, 5030", 
    MalKode  : "1-3"
  },
  {
    AdminID  : 6, 
    ProduktID: "07.1436", 
    itemName : "Repaplast grå", 
    itemColor: "0070", 
    MalKode  : "1-3"
  },
  {
    AdminID  : 146, 
    ProduktID: "90.0905", 
    itemName : "Mixer Gun", 
    itemColor: null, 
    MalKode  : ""
  },
  {
    AdminID  : 89, 
    ProduktID: "02.0135", 
    itemName : "Repaplast Primer NEW FORMULA", 
    itemColor: "", 
    MalKode  : "5-3"
  }
];

const filtered = products.filter((product) => wanted.includes(product.ProduktID));
console.log("Filtered", filtered);
```

Comment: It really looks like a great answer. Thank you. I will test it.

Comment: BUT where does the word "PRODUCT" come into play? you call the array "productS" I see no mention of "product" anywhere in the code except in the const filtered ??

Comment: `products.filter((----->product<-----) => { ... })` - it is an argument of the array function passed to the `.filter()` method

Comment: I get an error: "filter is not a function". when I try to add products.filter(...) Do I have to convert the products array in some special manner ?

Comment: i see now that my array is formatted sligthly different than in my initial question: it is really: {"products":[{"AdminID":491,"ProduktID":"01.0635","itemName":"ClearBond .... }]...}

Comment: assuming your array is assigned to `const array = { products: [ .... ] }`, you'd do it like this: `array.products.filter()`.