# JQuery: Why is ".filter not a function" in this script?

Tags: jquery, function, filter

I asked this question a few days ago: 
[Jquery grep or map object array with multiple search criterias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578837/jquery-grep-or-map-object-array-with-multiple-search-criterias)
And I quickly got two very promising answer. Alas, they both give me the following error in console.log:

**products.filter is not a function**

This is one of the promising scripts I received:
I have pasted the script into my editor unchanged and it will NOT run, at all.
Even tho the Code Snippet runs in the post I've linked to.

```js
const productIds = '07.1438, 01,1340, 05,04531, 02.0135';

    const products = [{AdminID: 137, ProduktID: "07.1438", itemName: "Repaplast", itemColor: "0000, 5030", MalKode: "1-3",},{AdminID: 6, ProduktID: "07.1436", itemName: "Repaplast grå", itemColor: "0070", MalKode: "1-3",},{AdminID: 146, ProduktID: "90.0905", itemName: "Mixer Gun", itemColor: null, MalKode: "",},{AdminID: 89, ProduktID: "02.0135", itemName: "Repaplast Primer NEW FORMULA", itemColor: "", MalKode: "5-3",}];

    var result = products.filter( o => productIds.split(',').find(productId => o.ProduktID === productId.trim()));

    console.log(result);
```

I have literately scoured the net for a solution, but I can not find anything remotely close to an answer. So I turn - once more to the brilliant minds at Stackoverflow. Can anyone in plain english try to explain to me what is wrong in this picture?

edit: Is this browser dependent?
I run Dreamweaver cs6 as my preferred editor. I have tested the script live in chrome and Opera. If this is browser dependent I may have to look for another solution, because this is going on my company website, and I cannot control the user preferred browser.

I really need to solve this I have spent a week on this thing and it drives me mad. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to run the code in an ES6 capable browser like Firefox or Chrome because it uses ES6's arrow syntax for function declaration. Looks like you might be using an Internet Explorer (which completely and utterly sucks compared to the two mentioned).

Comment: Works fine as you can see in stack snippets. Maybe you are missing some polyfills?

Comment: I am running it in both Chrome and Opera. And my preffered editor is DreamWeaver cs6. Are you saying this script is browser dependent? Then I have a major problem. This script is going on my homepage and I cannot control which browser my users prefer..... sigh

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ you can verify here

Comment: Looking at your original post, the object in the snippet is different from your original object. In the snippet the `Products` array seems to be used directly. Based on the error, I think you are using `filter` directly on your original variable, which is an object (and doesn't have the `filter` method). You could try `var result = yourObject.Products.filter(` etc

Answer (score 0):

First off, thank you for all valuable help and hints.
The comment "ES6 capable browser" made me think that Dreamweaver was part of the problem. It seems the editor throws an error that is simply not there.

furthermore:
I still need to tinker some on the scripts as I am using JSON.object (or whatever the correct term may be) as the source of data and as the source of the filter.

I've finally got the script working. So again., Thank you.